Read a huge file (~ 200GB) from a particular offset using liburing
Context: I need to read a huge file (~200 GB) from an offset, which is not a multiple of 512 (or block size), in chunks into a buffer as fast and as efficient as possible. A networking application utilizes this data in the buffer to create packets and send them out from the NIC. My sending rate is > 30 Gbps and thus I need to have data in the buffer always so that my networking application sender never runs out of data.
SSD details: KIOXIA XG8 Series (M.2) with 7000 GB/s (56 Gbps) max sequential read speed.
Initially I was using the libaio in the O_DIRECT mode and I was able to read fast enough (~50 Gbps) to have my application running. Since O_DIRECT mode enforces alignment requirements, I am looking for alternatives. In O_RDONLY mode, I am able to read the file at the required offset but that is very slow (reason could be that aio in non-O_DIRECT modes is not async IO anymore io_uring white paper.
As an alternative (better), I am using liburing to read my file. I am using O_RDONLY mode as it enables to read at any offset. However, the read speed it too low.
Here is my code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "liburing.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
    uint64_t block_size = 1 << 30;
    io_uring ring;
    io_uring_sqe *sqe;
    io_uring_cqe *cqe;
    void* buffer;
    uint64_t offset = 0;

    std::string file_name = "200GB_file";
    int file_fd = open(file_name.c_str(), O_RDONLY);
    if (file_fd < 0)
        throw "Cannot open file";

    uint64_t file_size = std::filesystem::file_size(file_name.c_str());
    uint64_t bytes_remaining = file_size;

    int num_entries = 1;
    int ret = io_uring_queue_init(num_entries, &ring, 0);
    if (ret < 0)
        throw "Error while initiating uring queue";

    if (posix_memalign(&buffer, block_size, block_size))
        throw "Error while mem-aligning";

    ret = io_uring_register_files(&ring, &file_fd, 1);
    if (ret)
        throw "failed to register file";

    while (bytes_remaining)
    {
        if (bytes_remaining < block_size)
            break;

        sqe = io_uring_get_sqe(&ring);
        if (!sqe)
            throw "Error while getting sqe";

        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        io_uring_prep_read(sqe, file_fd, buffer, block_size, offset);
        ret = io_uring_submit(&ring);
        if (ret < 0)
            throw "io uring submit error";

        ret = io_uring_wait_cqe(&ring, &cqe);
        if (ret < 0)
            throw "io uring wait error";


        std::cout << "cqe->res: " << cqe->res << " ";

        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto elapsed_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count();
        double reading_speed = double(block_size * 8) / double(elapsed_time);
        std::cout << " Reading speed: " << reading_speed << " Gbps" << std::endl;

        io_uring_cqe_seen(&ring, cqe);
        offset += block_size;
        bytes_remaining -= block_size;
    }

    close(file_fd);
    io_uring_queue_exit(&ring);
}

Here is the output (with offset = 0):
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 31.5145 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 73.4665 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 13.1884 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 6.37993 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 6.97253 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 6.41963 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 7.44832 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 7.40503 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 7.36463 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 6.78501 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 7.10513 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 7.05038 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 6.10796 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 5.63116 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 5.54613 Gbps
.
.
.

Here is the output (with offset = 10)
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 30.1049 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 76.969 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 74.8756 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 76.9209 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 77.1421 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 76.0599 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 77.7633 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 77.9113 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 75.8365 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 77.1777 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 76.6224 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 77.0741 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 77.0687 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 77.3948 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 76.1512 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 77.502 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 77.3421 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 77.4055 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 75.9798 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 55.6069 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 5.94714 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 32.7055 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 70.8435 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 23.822 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 5.69492 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 6.65288 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 6.76708 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 7.91575 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 6.29257 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 6.2675 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 7.31762 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 6.35138 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 7.52077 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 7.20884 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 6.05534 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 5.80964 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 6.58119 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 8.65097 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 27.1533 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 6.76254 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 5.9082 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 7.45788 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 6.89272 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 5.76414 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 5.65644 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 7.21536 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 6.09685 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 6.44203 Gbps
cqe->res: 1073741824  Reading speed: 6.97692 Gbps
.
.
.

In case of offset = 10, why do I see read speed values more than max read speed of the SSD (like 77 Gbps)?
Can the code be improved to give "better" read speeds? To quantify "better", let's say as close as possible to the maximum read speed supported by the SSD?

It may be what you were doing, but I'd just read with the alignment requirements, then compute the offset into the block, and send the data to the NIC from there. Reading a few extra kilobytes or so at the beginning and/or end is no big deal.

From my experience (writing at similar speeds, not reading), O_DIRECT will always provide the best performance. Maybe use normal IO for the first, partial block that is misaligned. You see read speeds above the disk speed because part of the data is probably cached in the page-cache. Either that or a disk-internal cache. libaio uses normal pread with a thread-pool. It is possible that the thread pool size is better than what the kernel uses with liburing. The important part is to keep the SSD busy with many overlapping operations. NVMe has deep queues

Do I interpret your ioring code correctly that you only submit one read command at a time and then wait for it to complete? That is inefficient. Try submitting 8 or so at a time and whenever one completes, start a new one. Keep multiple in-flight at all times

@Homer512 Here I am reading 1 GB at a time. So, I am submitting 1 read command at a time.

Sidenote: Don't use high_resolution_clock to measure. Use steady_clock since you don't want clock shifts to affect your measurements. high_resolution_clock is probably an alias for system_clock in your case, so not very trustworthy for making measurements.

There is no point in using just a single read command with liburing., The entire point is to keep many operations in-flight. If you want to do just a single large read, you can simply call pread
